# System.Xml.Linq Namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have been given the task of calling a web service which returns an xml data feed which I am doing like so;

```
For Each r As DataRow in SomeDataTable
    Dim msFeed As String = string.format("http://some-feed.com?param={0}", r!SOME_VAL)
    Dim x As XDocument = XDocument.Load(msFeed)
Next
```

This is all fine but as you can see x just gets overwritten with every iteration. What I need is create an xDocument and add each feed from my loop but I am unsure how to proceed.

Thanks

**Solution**

```
Dim xAllFeeds As XElement = New XElement("Feeds")

For Each r As DataRow in SomeDataTable
    Dim msFeed As String = string.format("http://some-feed.com?param={0}", r!SOME_VAL)
    Dim x As XDocument = XDocument.Load(msFeed)
    xAllFeeds.Add(x.Root)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure of the VB syntax (C# is my language of choice), but this should be the gist of what you're after.

```
Dim xAllFeeds As XElement = New XElement("Feeds")
For Each r As DataRow in SomeDataTable
    Dim msFeed As String = string.format("http://some-feed.com?param={0}", r!SOME_VAL)
    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(msFeed)
    xAllFeeds.Add(xDoc.Root)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, rather than 'AppendChild' i just used 'Add'

Comment: Sorry, It's not `AppendChild`, just `Add` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx).  I've adjusted the answer approriately.